# Feed not displaying images in Jekyll

Tags: jekyll

I've recently converted my [blog](https://danielmarcelino.github.io) to Jekyll environment, then I added the following particular feed which used by few site aggregators. However, I noticed that images are not being incorporated in the aggregators, for instance [here](http://www.statsblogs.com/2015/11/15/retrieving-data-from-google-books-with-ngramr/).

As I write the posts in markdown, I thought it could be some confusing image path, so I changed the path of couple posts from `![](/images/blog/2015/GoogleNgram.png)` to: `![]({{ site.url }}/images/blog/2015/GoogleNgram.png)` but nothing happened. Any advice will be highly appreciated.

```
---
layout: null
---
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
    <channel>
        <title>Daniel</title>
        <description>Posts categorized as 'R'</description>
        <link>{{ site.url }}</link>
        <atom:link href="{{ site.url }}/feed.r.xml" rel="self" type="application/rss+xml" />
        {% for post in site.posts %}
        {% if post.categories contains 'R' %}

            <item>
                <title>{{ post.title | xml_escape }}</title>
                {% if post.excerpt %}
                    <description>{{ post.excerpt | xml_escape }}</description>
                {% else %}
                    <description>{{ post.content | xml_escape }}</description>
                {% endif %}
                <pubDate>{{ post.date | date_to_rfc822 }}</pubDate>
                <link>{{ site.url }}{{ post.url }}</link>
                <guid isPermaLink="true">{{ site.url }}{{ post.url }}</guid>
            </item>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    </channel>
</rss>
```

Comment: http://www.danielmarcelino.com/ lands on a 403 / forbidden page. DNS problem. See https://help.github.com/articles/tips-for-configuring-a-cname-record-with-your-dns-provider/

Comment: That should be a github issue, it's working, though sometimes I have to refresh the page few times. The main issue is not the 403 thing, but he images + feed @DavidJacquel.

Comment: I can see images in your atom feed at http://danielmarcelino.com/atom.xml